# pip errors out with SSLError [X509] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4264) [Win10]

Tags: python, ssl, pip, ssl-certificate

I can't update anything/install anything new using `pip`, the following error keeps occurring:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(9, '[X509] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4264)'))': /simple/<package>
```

I can install using the extended command

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package_name>
```

and I updated and force reinstalled my `certifi` package using this.

I thought it was a CA cert issue but, this didn't change anything with the normal command.

What's going wrong? (and how do I fix it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I tried this before as well as mentioned in the question, but force-reinstalling `certifi` using the long command (with trusted hosts) solved it.

I cannot understand how it did not work when I asked the question.

One thing I can see being the problem is that when I did this the other day, it installed the most recent version of `certifi` at that time, which would be `2021.05.xx` (may 2021 basically). 
However, when it reinstalled today, it installed version `2021.10.8` (8th Oct 2021); which means a new update was released **yesterday**.

I wonder if I had installed an outdated/previous version (basically not the same version as `2021.05.xx`), would it have worked?